# NetworkManager is delaying my boot. How can I solve it without breaking functionality?

Tags: boot, wifi, networking

After a recent update or maybe after connecting to a TTLS  wifi network my boot time increased in 10 seconds.

I could make it faster by disabling "Connect automatically to this network" on the Network panel but that breaks the functionality since I have to connect manually to every network.

So is there a way to fix it without breaking my system? This issue started today (or maybe yesterday) and the only things that could trigger it are a system upgrade or the connection to said TTLS network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Masking `NetworkManager-wait-online.service` decreased boot time back to normal. I'm not sure what triggered it, but everything works fine now.

```
systemctl mask NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```